# Printing specified alphabet in pyramid format

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have some problem when trying to print out alphabet XXYY in half pyramid format using Java. Here is the expected output when user entered height of 7:

```
XX
YYXX
XXYYXX
YYXXYYXX
XXYYXXYYXX
YYXXYYXXYYXX
XXYYXXYYXXYYXX
```

And here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int height = 0;
    String display = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter height: ");
    height = sc.nextInt();

    for(int i = 1; i <= height; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            if(j %2 == 0){
                display = "YY" + display;
            }else{
                if(j == 1){
                    display = "XX";
                }
            }
            System.out.print(display);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

What my logic is I thinking to check for even/odd row first then add the XX or YY to the display string. First I check for first row, then I add XX to the display string. Then, if even row, I append YY to the front of the display string.

But my problem is I not sure how to count the amount of XX and YY for each row. Here is my output:

```
XX
XXYYXX
XXYYXXYYXX
XXYYXXYYXXYYYYXX
XXYYXXYYXXYYYYXXYYYYXX
XXYYXXYYXXYYYYXXYYYYXXYYYYYYXX
XXYYXXYYXXYYYYXXYYYYXXYYYYYYXXYYYYYYXX
```

Comment: you could made a little google for this simple logic . ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you're over-complicating things. In each row you have the same number of pairs of letters as the row number (one pair on the first row, two on the second, etc). The first row starts with "XX" and then the beginnings alternate between "XX" and "YY". In a similar fashion, within the row, after determining what you started with, you alternate between the two pairs of letters:

```
for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col <= row; ++col) {
        if ((col + row) % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print("XX");
        } else {
            System.out.print("YY");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand let's say we take row 1 for example. row 1 has 2 columns. So basically when row 1 + col 1 I printed out XX. Then isn't row 1 + col 2 %2 != 0? Then how come it never print out YY?

Comment: Instead of seeing every letter as an element in a column, @Mureinik considers the pairs as an element in a column. That why the first row only has one column, the second row has 2 columns, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int ht = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter height: ");
    ht = sc.nextInt();

    String text = "";
    for(int i=0; i<ht; i++)
    {
        if (i%2!=0)
            text = "YY" + text;
        else
            text = "XX" + text;
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

And works with single `for` loop too!

Comment: Thanks! This was much more straight forward!